# Can we tell if a program always returns 2 when it halts?

Tags: computability

Is the following computable ?

Notation: We use $Φ_k$ to denote the k-th computable function

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & ∀z (Φ_x(z) = 2 ∨ Φ_x(z) ↑) \\
↑\ &otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

I really need your help.

Thanks

Comment: When you write $\Phi x$ do you mean what is usually notated $\varphi_x$, that is, the $x$th partial recursive function in some fixed enumeration? And what's the meaning of the $\ge 0$ applied to a _logical formula_?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. > 0 was my mistake sorry i edited.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. In particular, what do you already know about computability, and what examples of noncomputable functions do you know?

Comment: This is what Rice's Theorem is about.

Comment: @MJD: there is at least something interesting in this problem: if we switch the $1$ and $\uparrow$ return value, the resulting function is partial computable. Because $g$ can be partial, Rice's theorem is not directly applicable.

Comment: As Carl said, you need to add more context. In particular, do you have a guess what the answer is? (For example, do you think you could figure out, in a finite amount of time, what $g(17)$ should be?)

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. By contradiction, suppose that g is computable, then so is 
$$ P\langle x,y\rangle=g(x) $$
By fixed point theorem, there is a $n$ such that $\Phi_n(y)$ computes $P\langle n,y\rangle$

Not that $\forall y \Phi_n(y)=1$ or $\forall y \Phi_n(y)\uparrow$ by definition (because it's always equal to $g(n)$)

But $\Phi_n(y)=P\langle n,y\rangle=g(n)=1$ iff $\Phi_n(y)\uparrow$

And $\Phi_n(y)=P\langle n,y\rangle=g(n)\uparrow$ iff $\Phi_n(y)=1$

This is a contradiction, hence $g$ is not computable.